# Visual Studio: How to use platform toolset as preprocessor directive?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, preprocessor-directive, project-properties

I have two platform toolsets: v110 and v110_xp for my project, and depending on the chosen platform I want to include/exclude part of the code to be compiled.

`_MSC_FULL_VER` and `$(PlatformToolsetVersion)` have exactly the same value for both of these platform toolsets. Alternatively, I tried to use `$(PlatformToolset)` as follows:

```
_MSC_PLATFORM_TOOLSET=$(PlatformToolset)
```

but the problem is that `$(PlatformToolset)` is non-numeric. Was wondering how can I use this non-numeric value as a preprocessor directive?

Trying several solutions I figured out that

```
_MSC_PLATFORM_TOOLSET='$(PlatformToolset)'
```

and then

```
#if (_MSC_PLATFORM_TOOLSET=='v110')
  [Something]
#endif
```

works fine but

```
#if(_MSC_PLATFORM_TOOLSET == 'v110_xp')
  [SomethingElse]
#endif
```

results in *"too many character in character constant"* error.

For the context please see this similar question:
[Visual Studio: how to check used C++ platform toolset programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13794130/visual-studio-how-to-check-used-c-platform-toolset-programmatically/23276277#23276277)

Answer (score 8):

Go to `project properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor` and add the following to `Preprocessor Definitions`:

`_MSC_PLATFORM_TOOLSET_$(PlatformToolset)`

Then you can write something like this:

```
#ifdef _MSC_PLATFORM_TOOLSET_v110
   [Something]
#endif

#ifdef _MSC_PLATFORM_TOOLSET_v110_xp
   [SomethingElse]
#endif
```

This works for me in VS2010.

Answer (score 4):

For VS 2012/2013, if you use backwards-compatibility toolset, **_USING_V110_SDK71_** will be available for you to use. VS2013 will define same name, regardless of platform toolset name, which is v120_xp.

```
#if (_MSC_VER >= 1700) && defined(_USING_V110_SDK71_)
    // working in XP-compatibility mode
#endif
```